# firebase cloud function using getSignedUrl for thumbnail is expiring after about a week, no clear reason why?

Tags: firebase, url, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm able to successfully generate a signedUrl for my thumbnails I am creating, but after about a week they no longer work...

I am not getting any errors or information as to why they are expiring, they just are.

I have been using firebase to develop my app and now all of a sudden I have to deal with all this google cloud storage permission and what not - really have no idea whats going on... It's got to be some sort of permission issue?

I have tried generating a new service account from the firebase console but no luck... I am tired of waiting weeks to see if they are going to expire again or not. I hope someone can guide me to a solution for this - it seems like its a problem for many people... We cant afford to go live and have gray thumbnails all over the app because they expire.

Here is how we are generating the signedUrl with firebase cloud functions:

```
    export const generateThumbs = functions.storage
      .object()
      .onFinalize(async object => {
          const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
          const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
          const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
          const userUid = filePath.split('/')[2];
          const sizes = [150, 256];
          const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

          if (!filePath.startsWith('categories/')) {
            console.log('This is not in the categories directory.');
            return false;
          }

          if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
              console.log('exiting function');
              return false;
            }

          const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
          const tempFilePath = path.join(tmpdir(), fileName);

          return bucket.file(filePath).download({
            destination: tempFilePath
          }).then(() => {

          sizes.map(size => {      
              const newFileName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`
              const newFileTemp = path.join(tmpdir(), newFileName);
              const newFilePath = `thumbs/${newFileName}`

              return sharp(tempFilePath)
                .resize(size, size)
                .toFile(newFileTemp, () => {

                  return bucket.upload(newFileTemp, {
                      destination: join(bucketDir, newFilePath),
                      metadata: {
                          contentType: 'image/jpeg'
                        }
                  }).then((data) => {
                      const file = data[0]
                      file.getSignedUrl({
                        action: 'read',
                        expires: '03-17-2100'
                      }, function(err, url) {
                        if (err) {
                          console.error(err);
                          return;
                        }
                        if (size === 150) {
                          return admin.database().ref('profileThumbs').child(userUid).child(fileName).set({ thumb: url });
                        } else if (size === 256) {
                          return admin.database().ref('categories').child(fileName).child('thumb').set(url)
                          .then(() => {
                            admin.database().ref('categories').child(fileName).child('tempThumb').remove();
                          })
                        }
                      })
                    })
                })
            })
          }).catch(error =>{
              console.log(error);
            });
        })
```

After setting the expiration date to 03-17-2100, we don't expect this type of behaviour, but like I said I feel like its something to do with gcs permissions - I tried to contact them but after about a week I am still waiting for their response.

I appreciate all the feedback!

Comment: See this comment on this issue: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/244#issuecomment-405661688

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin. So it seems like this is just a no go unless you only want the urls for a short period of time... any recommendations for a workaround? From what I have been seeing this is the only way right now to get a url from firebase cloud functions to the realtime database.

Comment: Mike's explanation summarizes a solution. Using it, you would create and then provide the email address of a service account (that you create and assign permisions). This new account is not subject to the 7-day limit caused by the rotation of the Firebased-provided service account. HTH.